# search and replace inside files usind Delphi language

Tags: delphi, search, replace

I want to make a small app with Delphi to search inside files for a specific word and change it then save the file

It should support ansi and utf-8, how I should do that ?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

If this is Delphi 2007 or older, you should probably use my [GpTextFile](http://gp.17slon.com/gp/gptextfile.htm) unit (which also works in Delphi 2009 and 2010).

In D2009+ you can use TEncoding converters to achieve simillar effect. See these StackOverflow topics for more information:

[Open an ANSI file and Save a a Unicode file using Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158382/open-an-ansi-file-and-save-a-a-unicode-file-using-delphi)

[How can a text file be converted from ANSI to UTF-8 with Delphi 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710992/how-can-a-text-file-be-converted-from-ansi-to-utf-8-with-delphi-7)